# Get the SQL query result without the table format

Tags: mysql, sql, shell

Like the `--disable-column-names` option, do we have an option to get the SQL query without the table format? For example:

```
mysql -u username -p password  --disable-column-names --execute "select name from test"
```

results below:

```
-----
| A |
| B |
| C |
| D |
-----
```

Is it possible to get the query result using some sql program option modifiers as below, **without the table format**?

I want this:

```
A
B
C
D
```

Comment: you can use `SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE 'file_name' export_options `

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Add the `-B` flag to `mysql`.

```sh
mysql -B -u username -ppassword \
    --disable-column-names \
    --execute "select name from mydb.test"
```

```
-B, --batch: Print results in nontabular output format.

--execute: Execute the statement and quit.
```

Note that `-B`/`--batch` also enables the `--silent` switch.

Comment: nice for an export - any way to do it within the mysql client?

Comment: `-b` is deprecated, use `--batch` instead.

Comment: anyway to do it from an sql script?

Comment: It's a good idea to add the `--database <database-name>`option to the commandline.

Answer (score 32):

Although the other answers work incidentally, the correct switch is actually `-s` which is short for `--silent`.

You may want to additionally specify `-r` for `--raw` output, which disables character escaping as well, otherwise newline, tab, null char and backslash will be represented as \n, \t, \0 and \ respectively.

> ```
>    ·   --silent, -s
>
>        Silent mode. Produce less output. This option can be given multiple
>        times to produce less and less output.
>
>        This option results in nontabular output format and escaping of
>        special characters. Escaping may be disabled by using raw mode; see
>        the description for the --raw option.
>
>    ·   --raw, -r
>
>        For tabular output, the “boxing” around columns enables one column
>        value to be distinguished from another. For nontabular output (such
>        as is produced in batch mode or when the --batch or --silent option
>        is given), special characters are escaped in the output so they can
>        be identified easily. Newline, tab, NUL, and backslash are written
>        as \n, \t, \0, and \\. The --raw option disables this character
>        escaping.
>
>        The following example demonstrates tabular versus nontabular output
>        and the use of raw mode to disable escaping:
>
>            % mysql
>            mysql> SELECT CHAR(92);
>            +----------+
>            | CHAR(92) |
>            +----------+
>            | \        |
>            +----------+
>            % mysql -s
>            mysql> SELECT CHAR(92);
>            CHAR(92)
>            \\
>            % mysql -s -r
>            mysql> SELECT CHAR(92);
>            CHAR(92)
>            \
> ```
>
> - Oracle Corporation
>
> MySQL 5.7                         06/07/2018