# bash - extract data from mysql table (GROUP BY)- how to process

Tags: mysql, json, bash

I have mySQL table:

```
+----+---------------------+-------+
| id | timestamp           | value |
+----+---------------------+-------+
|  1 | 2016-03-29 18:53:28 |     1 |
|  2 | 2016-03-29 20:26:06 |     1 |
|  3 | 2016-03-29 20:26:22 |     1 |
+----+---------------------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

It is a table to hold water consumption data (each 1 in `value` is a 1 liter of water).

I wrote a bash script to extract data - sum of litres of water by months.

```
watersum=`echo " SELECT MONTHNAME(timestamp), SUM(value) FROM woda GROUP BY YEAR(timestamp), MONTH(timestamp);" | mysql  -s -u$SQUSER -p$SQPASS -h$SQHOST $SQLDB` 

echo $watersum
```

gives me:

```
March 693 April 9768 May 11277 June 11987 July 10047 August 8570
```

I would like to save this data in json file. How do convert the string in `$watersum` to a json string?

Comment: See: [get the sql query result with out table format](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16711844/3776858)

Comment: I have now result without table names but how to split this variable which contains "March 693 April 9768 May 11277 June 11987 July 10047 August 8570
" onto json format file with months and values?

Comment: Save the output to a temp file and read it line by line.

Answer (score 1):

Make `watersum` an array

```
watersum=( $(echo " SELECT MONTHNAME(timestamp), SUM(value) FROM woda GROUP BY YEAR(timestamp), MONTH(timestamp);" | mysql  -s -u$SQUSER -p$SQPASS -h$SQHOST $SQLDB) )

echo "{" && for((i=0;i<"${#watersum[@]}";i+=2))
do  
echo -n "\"${watersum[$i]}\":\"${watersum[((i+1))]}\""; 
(( (i+2) == "${#watersum[@]}" )) || echo ","
done && echo;echo "}"
```

**Output**

```
{
"March":"693",
"April":"9768",
"May":"11277",
"June":"11987",
"July":"10047",
"August":"8570"
}
```