# Shell Script – Get Extract value from mysql show variables

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I want to get a value form show variables query using the shell script. This is the command i used.

```
data=$(mysql -u root -proot -t -e "show variables where variable_name = 'datadir';"  -B --skip-column-names)
```

Out put result is,

```
+---------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name | Value           |
+---------------+-----------------+
| datadir       | /var/lib/mysql/ |
+---------------+-----------------+
```

So i just want to get the value.

```
/var/lib/mysql/
```

This is the Script which i try,

```
data=$(mysql -u root -proot -t -e "show variables where variable_name = 'datadir';"  -B --skip-column-names)
data2=$(echo $data | tr "+---------+-----------------+" "\n")
data3=$(echo $data2 | tr "|" "\n")
data4=$(echo $data3 | tr "datadir " "\n")
echo $data4
```

its returning "/v /l b/mysql/".

Comment: Instead of fiddling with shell to get rid of the borders, I'd rather make MySQL not print them in the first place.

Comment: Get rid of the `-t` option. It's overriding `-B`, so you get the borders.

Comment: Thanks border removed. But how to get the remove "datadir" from the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't use the `-t` and `-B` options together (in addition, prefer `--batch` over `-B`, as `-B` is deprecated (see [Get the sql query result without the table format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711598/get-the-sql-query-result-without-the-table-format)).

Next, `tr` is intended to replace single characters only. If you want to replace more characters, you could use `sed` or just Bash. If you want the second word in a string of characters, you could use `cut`.

**Pure Bash**

```sh
data=$(mysql -u root -proot -e "show variables where variable_name = 'datadir';"  --batch --skip-column-names)
echo "${data//datadir/}"
```

**sed**

```sh
data=$(mysql -u root -proot -e "show variables where variable_name = 'datadir';"  --batch --skip-column-names)
sed 's/datadir//g' <<< "$data"
```

**cut**

```sh
data=$(mysql -u root -proot -e "show variables where variable_name = 'datadir';"  --batch --skip-column-names)
cut -d' ' -f2 <<< "$data"
```